# how to execute logout trigger and do ngIf authentication check - Angular 4 and Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, ionic3

I have 2 problems here:

I am not sure how to **attach below Logout function to Logout Button**, as you can see I am populating pages using *ngFor Directive.

I have (click)=openPage(p) but for Logout page it should execute Logout function instead of opening a page.

Also, **Angular does not allow multiple *directives (for example: *ngIf and *ngFor) on the same element** so how do I **check for isAuthenticated to hide or show menu buttons.** the tricky bit is that if user is not authenticated then I want to show 3 pages : login, register, contact and if authenticated show all other.

## app.component.ts

```
this.pages = [
  { title: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardPage, icon: 'stats'  },
  { title: 'Analytics', component: TabsPage, icon: 'analytics'  },
  { title: 'Portfolio', component: ProtabsPage, icon: 'images'  },
  { title: 'Profile', component: PtabsPage, icon: 'person'  },
  { title: 'Customize', component: SettingsPage, icon: 'options'  },
  { title: 'Contact', component: ContactPage, icon: 'call'  },
  { title: 'Logout', component: DashboardPage, icon: 'log-out'  },
  { title: 'Register', component: RegisterPage, icon: 'person-add'  },
  { title: 'Login', component: LoginPage, icon: 'log-in'  }
  ];
this.activePage = this.pages[1];

Logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
}
```

## authService.ts

```
logout(): void
{
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.isLoggedin = false;
    //Redirect to Login Page
}
```

## app.html

```
  <button padding ion-item class="menu-btn" text-center *ngFor="let p of pages" [class.activeHighlight]="checkActive(p)" (click)="openPage(p)">
    <ion-icon  name="{{p.icon}}" ></ion-icon>
    <h4>{{p.title}}</h4>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`ng-container`** with **`*ngIF`**

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let p of pages">
<button  *ngIf="isLoggedin && p.title ==='Logout'" padding ion-item class="menu-btn" text-center  [class.activeHighlight]="checkActive(p)" (click)="Logout (p)">
    <ion-icon  name="{{p.icon}}" ></ion-icon>
    <h4>{{p.title}}</h4>
  </button>
<button  *ngIf="!isLoggedin"  padding ion-item class="menu-btn" text-center  [class.activeHighlight]="checkActive(p)" (click)="openPage(p)">
    <ion-icon  name="{{p.icon}}" ></ion-icon>
    <h4>{{p.title}}</h4>
 </button>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: logout button takes me to the dashboard page for some reason. any idea? also I dont need to pass the p to the Logout(p).

Comment: just change the function according to your need

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to logical management inside the class. Instead of fixed open() method, put a method which will call corresponding method (open/logout, etc..) depending on the component that  used it. You can even add more checks here, like if it's logged or not.